# How to return value inside a lambda

Tags: java, android, lambda

I am new with java 8 and lambda and I don't know what should I do for returning value inside a lambda .
I tried this code but return null value but in the logs the token is logged.
also i tried static value but it didn't work. i want to return this value in another java class and use it .

```java
 public  String GetToken(Context context,String user_name,String password) throws JSONException {
        RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
        jsonBody.put("user_name", user_name);
        jsonBody.put("password", password);
        final String mRequestBody = jsonBody.toString();

        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(
                    Request.Method.POST,
                    url,
                    response -> {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jso = new JSONObject(response);
                            String token=jso.getString("token");
                            result=token;
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Log.i("GetTokene",e.toString());
                            result=e.toString();
                        }
                    },
                    error -> {
                        Log.i("GetTokenE",error.toString());
                         result=error.toString();
                    }
            ) {
                @Override
                public String getBodyContentType() {
                    return "application/json";
                }
                @Override
                public byte[] getBody() {
                    try {
                        return mRequestBody == null ? null : mRequestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                        // VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", mRequestBody, "utf-8");
                        return null;
                    }
                }              
            };

            requestQueue.add(request);
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Please take time to read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: what is wrong with my asking method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because a lambda is used instead of annonymous class, its still a callback, and its still going to be called asynchronously.  This means that it can't return a value to the calling code, because it will be called sometime in the future.  You have to put all code that requires the result into the lambda, either directly or by calling it from there.

Comment: I want to use the token in another java class what should I do ?

Comment: Pass it to that class inside the lambda

Comment: there are 30 class I should past this code in all classes , is there easy way to do that  ? i need token value only

Comment: could you please help me more how can I save token value ?